# How to query large table and list object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a large table 1.2 million or so rows that I need to query using. Contains on the same field. There is a field combined_name that needs to be queried using a list. I am trying to do it with just one field for now to check performance and that is reflected in the code. The way I have it written takes far too long.  Is there a way where I don't have to load the table into memory?

```
JDataClassDataContext db = new JDataClassDataContext();
var fullName = txtSearchBox0.Text.Trim();
List<string> firstName = new List<string>(txtSearchBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToString(x)).ToList());

var rows = (from c in db.defendants_ALLs.AsEnumerable()
      where c.combined_name.Contains(fullName)
          && firstName.Any(n => c.combined_name.Contains(n))
      select c).ToList();     

dlSearch.DataSource = rows;
dlSearch.DataBind();
```

Comment: can't you have fullname as a field in your database table? In your current setting there is no way a rdbms will use an index. It fallsback to a full table scan, hence the performance hit.

Comment: fullname is a field on a webpage that needs to be input by the user so no it cannot be in the database.  I have to fields txtSearch0 and txtSearch1 each of which requires an input from the user to search the combined_name for the correct names.  For instance txtSearch0 = 'smit' and txtSearch1 = 'joh,jon,j.' to get all the different spellings and the random j. smith that happens to be in the data we get.  I am thinking stored procedure may be the best option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

check out [Skip()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/skip) and [Take()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/take) methods.

You can use it like this:

```
var rows = (from c in db.defendants_ALLs.AsEnumerable()
           where c.combined_name.Contains(fullName)
           && firstName.Any(n => c.combined_name.Contains(n))
           select c).OrderBy(o => o.id).Skip(amount).Take(otherAmount).ToList();
```

Where `amount` and `otherAmount` represent the amount of records you want to actually fetch from the database. This means that you can for instace only ask for 30 records, instead of the full 1.2 million (== what would happen if you would just do a `.ToList()`)

Comment: Would using skip() and take() get all the correct records?  The issue is the field can contain strings such as 'smith john', 'smith j.', 'john smith', 'john d. smith', 'smith d. john', 'smith john d.'.

Comment: That depends on what you call "correct records". Using skip&take could mean that you take 40 records where a name contains "john", but it might be that there are actually over 200 records that contain the name "John". Those other records won't be fetched from the database.

Comment: The 'correct records' would be all records that include 'jon,joh,j.' AND 'smit'.  We then have to narrow those records down by hand because of human input error.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to generate a good oldfasion SQL query like
"SELECT fields FROM table WHERE combined_name LIKE '%fullname%' AND firstName IN ('first', 'next',...)"
You should take a look at SqlConnection and SqlCommand and SqlDataReader.  It is a little more different than linq, but it is much faster (if you have the right indexes)

Comment: Would using a stored procedure be even faster?  The indices are correct and we have an Access app that already performs this same function but we want to rid ourselves of Access.